# Adding a select all, uncheck all function to my filter checkboxes react+typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I created this function which is a filter with checkboxes.
How can I add the functionality where you can check all/uncheck all to my existing code, aslo adding typescript to it?

Any help is very appreciated!

```
function FilterCheckbox(props) {
  const wells = ["All","Legacy Wells", "Injection Wells", "Monitoring Wells"];
  const [checkedWells, setCheckedWells] = useState([]);

  const wellsProps = { wells, checkedWells, setCheckedWells };
  return (
    <div>
      <CheckedWells {...wellsProps} />
    </div>
  );
}

function CheckedWells(props) {
  const handleChecked = e => {
    const well = props.wells[e.target.dataset.id];
    let newCheckedWells = props.checkedWells.filter(item => item !== well);
    if (e.target.checked) newCheckedWells.push(well);
    props.setCheckedWells(newCheckedWells);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {props.wells.map((well, id) => (
        <label key={id}>
          <input type="checkbox" data-id={id} onClick={handleChecked} /> {well}
        </label>
      ))}

      <p>{props.checkedValues}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
export default FilterCheckbox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add `checked`attribute and handle your logic there. For example `checked={props.checkedWells.includes(<your logic here>)`

Comment: Hi @Ozan 
Could you guide in the right direction please? Where in my code can I add this and can I use the logic I already have? Thank you!

Comment: okay, first put this checked attribute on your input, then create two functions. first to fill all and second to delete all. the logic behind this is to set an empty array for cleaning and put wells in the state as you defined in the parent. this part was filling and clearing the wells array. In the input part, you have to check the boxes and for that, you need to use the attribute I mentioned before. If checked equals true it is going to be filled in. So if your array has its value it will be checked. I prepared a sandbox for you but actually was going to send it later but I m going to sleep

Comment: I would recommend you to try to implement it by yourself first but if you have trouble, here is the code for you https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-sinoussi-w6fkeo?file=/src/Well.js I hope it helps you, if not we can look it again together. Have a nice night